# Create CSV File in PHP and Save to SFTP using phpseclib

Tags: php, csv, mysqli, phpseclib

I need to generate a `CSV` file from a `MySQL` query and save the file to an `SFTP` server.  I have tried the code below.  The `CSV` file gets created, but it is empty.  I also receive an error message in the browser that says `Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given` in regard to this line `$sftp->put($fileName, $fp, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);`.  If I move `fclose($fp);` to the last line, I don't get the error but data still doesn't appear in the file.  Could someone please let me know how to get the data to save in the file that was created?

```
$fileName = 'dataFiles/reports/Report Summary/Report Summary.csv';
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "
        SELECT *
        FROM   reports
        WHERE reportID = 1
");

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$first = true;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    if ($first) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row));
        $first = false;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
$sftp->put($fileName, $fp, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#put - you need to give this method either a string of data to write, or the name of a local file to read the content to be written from - not a file pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
// do stuff
rewind($fp);
$sftp->put($filename, $fp);
```

phpseclib (assuming you're using a new enough version) will detect that the second parameter is a stream resource and will try to read from it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the `rewind($fp);` and moving `fclose($fp);` to the end of what I already had was the key.

Comment: I followed your answer. It works correctly but my CSV is empty.

Comment: I solved with @Roukmoute answer adding stream_get_contents

Answer (score 1):

The [second argument](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#put) is not a handle but the content directly.

I think you could do: `stream_get_contents($fp);` in the second argument.

```
$content = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);
$sftp->put($fileName, $content, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: Have you tried with `$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');` and before `stream_get_contents`, do a `rewind($fp);`?

Comment: Because your `php://output` I/O stream has this definition: `php://output is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as print and echo.` Change it by `php://temp`

Comment: Yeah I just read that. Ok, using `$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');` gives me `Notice: is not a valid file`